# How to listen letter keys with combination of modifier keys using pynput?

Tags: python, pynput

I am tying to automate some stuff using python.I use pynput to listen key combinations. I am trying to listen ctrl+shift+alt s combination. I have no problem with modifier keys but only with letter keys. I have looked the python documentation page and tried followings:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from evdev import uinput, ecodes as e
import os

# The key combination to check
COMBINATION = {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.Key.alt, keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('k')}

# The currently active modifiers
current = set()

def on_press(key):
    if key in COMBINATION:
        current.add(key)
        if all(k in current for k in COMBINATION):
            print("x")
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        listener.stop()

def on_release(key):
    try:
        current.remove(key)
    except KeyError:
        pass

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

After running the python file from terminal, script cannot detect my key combination.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs, you can use this method. https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_activate():
    print('Global hotkey activated!')

def for_canonical(f):
    return lambda k: f(l.canonical(k))

hotkey = keyboard.HotKey(
    keyboard.HotKey.parse('<ctrl>+<alt>+h'),
    on_activate)
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=for_canonical(hotkey.press),
        on_release=for_canonical(hotkey.release)) as l:
    l.join()
```

Comment: I already saw that, but I cannot see anything about letter keys in this code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: That's the answer I've been searching for hours ! Thanks, that works perfectly ! :D

Comment: To me, this feels like a lazy contribution, without really taking time to think about op's needs and code. This is just a copy-paste from the documentation, without the above, or explaining why it applies to OPs question.

Comment: Code is syntactically broken; line 7 `l.canonical`references `l` before assignment

Comment: `keyboard.HotKey` does not work for me, but `keyboard.GlobalHotKeys` does.

Answer (score 0):

When you press `<shift> + k`, the letter typed is capital 'K', which is not equal to lowercase 'k'. Note that Sri's answer passes the key through `listener.canonical`, which turns the capital letter into a lowercase one.

I suggest you add the following line at the start of `on_press`:

```
    key = listener.canonical(key)
```

Using the global `listener` object like this makes me uncomfortable. It will break if you split your code into modules. Unfortunately, it appears to be the intended usage.

For some reason, `listener.canonical(keyboard.Key.esc) != keyboard.Key.esc`. Consider moving your escape clause to precede `key = listener.canonical(key)` as well.

Also note that, on my platform (X window manager on Ubuntu), pynput does not correctly interpret `<shift> + <alt>` as just `<alt>`. I have to type the keys in this order: `<alt> + <ctrl> + <shift> + k`. I suggest not using `shift + alt` key combinations if you can avoid it. If you get mysterious errors with key combinations, try printing out the keys so you can see what pynput thinks they are.